# How to add Jboss server in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Does anyone know how to setup JBoss server in IntelliJ and debug J2EE application from within the IDE?

When I click on + sign in Settings > Plugins there is no option for JBoss.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First of all You need the Ultimate version:
then:

Settings > Build, Executions, Deployment -> Application Servers > "+" > JBOss Server

Comment: Well, this could be my problem. I am using Community version...so are you sure this would not be available with Community version?

Comment: Im sure. Server support only on ultimate.

Comment: Wouldn't mind buying IntelliJ license but the renew every year kind of stinks. But thank you very much for the information.

Comment: @Athi I added the JBoss server. Now, how do I run/debug my JBoss App directly from the IDE?

Comment: @DilipRajBaral The easiest way: Alt + Shift + F10 -> After that You should see a pop up window with list of configurations to run.

Comment: you may also need to add Jboss integration plugin in Settings->Plugin https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=93130951 before

Comment: @samir If you buy IntelliJ for one year and never renew it, you still get to use the last version of that year forever. You just don't get more updates. Then say 4 years down the road, you can buy it again to get new features.

Answer (score 13):

Basically I wanted to debug my code deployed to JBoss server inside the IDE. This can be achieved by connecting to JBoss server remotely. See the images below.

Make sure when you start JBoss you have made a change in standalone.bat file to enable debug port. Note the debug port as you have to specify it when you create remote configuration in IntelliJ or Eclipse. Start your JBoss Server and then click on the new remote configuration that you created.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Only for Ultimate Edition.

1. Go to Run > Edit Configurations.
2. Select + > JBoss Server > Local.
3. Name the configuration (for example "WF15")
4. Press Configure and browse to the installation path of WildFly.
5. Go to the Deployment tab and add the exploded WAR (choose from the dropdown).
6. Go back to the Server tab -> select "Redeploy" from On 'Update' action
   and uncheck the "Show Dialog".
7. Run the configuration.

WildFly will start and deploy the exploded WAR. A server tab "WF15" will appear at the base of the IDE.

Comment: Had it been more indented, it would have been more accepted.

Comment: I had to visit here twice and both the times this answer beat all the answers anywhere on internet. This saved me a lot of head-scratching.

Comment: Except that this is not available in the Community version

Answer (score 0):

You can type <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> ( or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> on windows ) to access the action pop-up, then type something like `add server` and choose the 'server' option. This will bring you to the application servers panel of the preferences where you can add (`+`) the JBoss server.

Note: you only have JEE support in the ultimate version. The open-source version doesn't have this capability.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use Intellij in ubuntu for project1 development, debug and git operations then use following steps :-

Import project1 in intellij as normal project.

To start jboss without eclipse use following

Go to terminal JBOSS_HOME/bin

To start project1 , with debug port /home/applicationName/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=,server=y,suspend=n -Dprogram.name=JBossTools: -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/home/applicationName//wildfly-9.0.1.Final/standalone_project1/log/boot.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/home/applicationName//wildfly-9.0.1.Final/standalone_project1/configuration/logging.properties -Djboss.home.dir=/home/applicationName//wildfly-9.0.1.Final -Dorg.jboss.logmanager.nocolor=true -Djboss.bind.address.management=localhost -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/applicationName//wildfly-9.0.1.Final/jboss-modules.jar:/home/applicationName/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/jre/lib/resources.jar:/home/applicationName/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/applicationName/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/home/applicationName/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/jre/lib/jce.jar:/home/applicationName/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/home/applicationName/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/jre/lib/jfr.jar org.jboss.modules.Main -mp /home/applicationName//wildfly-9.0.1.Final/modules -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -b 0.0.0.0 --server-config=standalone.xml -Djboss.server.base.dir=/home/applicationName//wildfly-9.0.1.Final/standalone_project1 -Dcom.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.lookupExtensionInBeanManager=true -Djboss.node.name=project1

Replace java path /home/applicationName/.sdkman/candidates/java/current with your java path in above commands.
Replace wildfly path /home/applicationName//wildfly-9.0.1.Final with your wildfly path in above commands.

Now configure intellij to debug to remote application.

Note, we have still possibility to improve this command by replacing JBOSS_HOME, JAVA_HOME and others, which I haven't done yet.

Answer (score -1):

You can type cmd+shift+a ( or ctrl+shift+a on windows ) to access the action pop-up, then type something like add server and choose the 'server' option. This will bring you to the application servers panel of the preferences where you can add (+) the JBoss server.

Note: you only have JEE support in the ultimate version. The open-source version doesn't have this capability.